# Enable hidden hardware virtualization settings

Tags: windows-7, virtualization, bios

I am trying to get the Windows XP emulation up and running on my new Windows 7 Professional installation and I found out that you need to enable hardware virtualization.

I have a HP Media Center PC m7428n, I checked and it has an AMD Athlon 64 X2 4200 processor which should be able to handle hardware virtualization, but the BIOS setup has no option for it. I checked around and most people have said the HP often hides certain BIOS settings.

Is there any way to get around this and enable it anyway?

Comment: Try running the SecurAble to determine whether your processor actually supports virtualization http://www.grc.com/securable.htm

Comment: as a side note - this is one of the major things I hate about the brand-name PC market (HP, Dell, etc): you can't make changes that *should* be possible a lot of the time :-\

Comment: Another side note: By now XP mode does not require hardware virtualization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although many sources claim that virtualization works on your model, it's not an absolute certainity.

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_Athlon_64_microprocessors#Athlon_64_X2), the Athlon 64 X2 4200+ has two models with part numbers ADA4200DAA5BV or ADA4200BVBOX. This seems to be a confusion - there seems to be only a single model.

The site [products.amd.com](http://products.amd.com/en-us/DesktopCPUDetail.aspx?id=72&f1=&f2=&f3=&f4=&f5=&f6=&f7=&f8=&f9=&f10=&f11=&f12=) elaborates some more, detailing both the above numbers, but calling them rather `OPN Tray ADA4200DAA5BV` and `OPN PIB ADA4200BVBOX`. **It also says
"Virtualization : No".**

To further verify the issue, you may use either [SecurAble](http://www.grc.com/files/securable.exe) or Microsoft's [Hardware-Assisted Virtualization Detection Tool](http://depositfiles.com/files/61ohffu1d) (made available by [mydigitallife](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2009/10/10/hardware-assisted-virtualization-hav-detection-tool-free-download/)).

Comment: Ran the both of the Detection tools and both said that I had no hardware virtulization capabilty... thanks

Comment: Try to use Microsoft's Virtual PC for creating the XP virtual machine. This product predates hardware virtualization and might work for you.

Comment: Hmm... That is the exact program I am trying to run but sadly it requires hardware virtulization for windows 7

Comment: Have you tried http://www.virtualbox.org/ ?

Comment: yea, but not the same thing sadly, I was hopeing to use the built in hardware virtulization but otherwise I can just use vm, However i have used virtual box before and it is pretty amazeing

Comment: I've seen some benchmarks suggesting that the performance of hardware-assisted and software-only virtualization are not very different.