# How do I find and enable the virtualization setting on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, bios, virtualization

I am trying to install Docker for Windows. During installation, I get this error:

> **An error occurred**
>
> Hardware assisted virtualization and data execution protection must be enabled in the BIOS. See https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/troubleshoot/#virtualization-must-be-enabled
>
> [image: Error on Docker installation]

The link directs me to use Task Manager to determine whether or not virtualization is enabled. It's not, of course!

### How do I find the BIOS setting to enable virtualization?

I can enter the BIOS, but I have to search around an awful lot...

Relevant info: BIOS Version/Date: American Megatrends Inc. 3201, 12/27/2016

Note: I searched for similar questions on this topic, but there were no solutions that worked for me:

- [Virtualization BIOS setting Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/991323/virtualization-bios-setting-windows-10)
- [How to Enable Virtualization Windows 10, InsydeH20](https://superuser.com/questions/1031597/how-to-enable-virtualization-windows-10-insydeh20)
- [Enable hidden hardware virtualization settings](https://superuser.com/questions/53824/enable-hidden-hardware-virtualization-settings)
- [how to enable virtualization in BIOS settings](https://superuser.com/questions/889850/how-to-enable-virtualization-in-bios-settings)
- [Enable Virtualization for Windows 10 Pro running inside VirtualBox](https://superuser.com/questions/1144405/enable-virtualization-for-windows-10-pro-running-inside-virtualbox)
- [Virtual Box 4 and VT-x enable settings](https://superuser.com/questions/376828/virtual-box-4-and-vt-x-enable-settings)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For certain BIOS versions like this one:

BIOS Version/Date: American Megatrends Inc. 3201, 12/27/2016

1. Restart the machine
2. During restart, press <kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>Delete</kbd> to enter BIOS
3. Advanced --> CPU configuration --> Intel Virtualization Technology --> Enabled --> Exit --> Save Changes & Reset --> OK

Now I can install Docker!